# How to determine 500 error and show custom error message

Tags: php, codeigniter, http, codeigniter-3

I am trying to import some data from an excel sheet then insert this data in my database, what i want is that if the user uploaded huge amount of entries lets say 16000 entry in excel sheet and tried to upload huge amount of data on my server then the server shows 500 internal server or server to handle this request on browser so i have to catch this error in php server side and show my custom message to the user.

For this i have tried to catch this but it is not working, so please help me.

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    function import_client()
    {
        try
        {
            //my php code in this i am reading excel
            //sheet data and inserting in my database.
        }
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            echo "you are importing huge data
            hence server will not unable to handle this request";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: If the error 500 root cause is on database side, i would handle exception on database side. Then return a flag on php and display your custom message. For example on MySQL: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-error-handling-in-stored-procedures/

Answer (score 0):

error code 500 is internal server error. it shows when you have error at your server. it wont perform any service after that. so there is no way you can handle it.

Comment: Not entirely accurate. The HTTP 500 error is thrown by the webserver (Apache, Nginx, etc) due to something happening on the server side which is less detailed and granular than other 5xx errors, but it can still be managed to produce a more explicit (and less information-disclosure prone) way than a generic HTTP 500 error. Error handling in codeigniter is very possible as described [In the user guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html)

Comment: i wont re command you to do this. you can use htaccess to redirect your error pages. try this out : https://paulund.co.uk/use-htaccess-to-redirect-custom-error-pages

Comment: yes, that's another alternative if (big IF) you use Apache. there's similar ways to handle errors in Nginx too. However, a combination of that and code-based error handling is the correct approach.

Comment: I am not sure. but as i work i am sure it is so rare to see error code 500. but give it a try. i guess there is no other way to handel error code 500,501 or so on. it is best way that i know.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using CodeIgniter, error handling can be performed with CI's built-in functionality described [Here, in CI's User Guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html)

That said, error handling should be the final layer of properly coded applications for all cases that haven't been explicitly caught by try-catching or other methodologies. You should, at least on your dev environment, try to reproduce the error with full logging and error reporting enabled and try to figure out how to prevent the error (and not just handling it when it occurs).

Many things come to mind, even though you're not providing much data. If the 5xx error is being triggered by an extremely long processing time, you may consider splitting the uploaded sheet into chunks and process it in batches. Maybe your database is acting up, in which case you may be facing server spec issues or even to many index calculations upon every insert. The sheet itself may contain something that's messing with your inserts (violating table/field definitions, for instance).

Have you tried to determine the cause of the error?